# Git doesn't show working/remote differences

Tags: git

The remote branch looks dramatically different than my working. Yet when I try 
`git diff HEAD..origin/branch` it shows no differences at all. Even more interesting, when I do `git pull` it doesn't overwrite my working. What are the options here?

Answer (score 0):

`origin/branch` isn't always the same as `origin branch`. The first one is a local branch name; it **can** be linked to a remove branch on `origin` but not necessarily. `origin branch` means "remote=`origin`, remote branch=`branch`" (but this syntax isn't available in `git diff`).

Try `git show <ref>` to see which the commit `<ref>` points to. Then you can check on the remote if that's the latest branch or not.

Also check your `.git/config` and the tracking information for your branch.

Another source for this problem could be that you merged your branch with the remote using a special strategy like `ours` which tells Git that there are no differences between the branches anymore and your local version should be used from now on.

`git pull` will only update your current branch. If you're on a new branch or if your branch hasn't changed on the remote server, then `git pull` won't do much.

So if I work on branch `foo` and I push that but you're on `bar`, `git pull` won't merge my work in `foo` into your branch. Someone would have to commit/push work to the remote `bar` branch instead.